# `@apply` cannot be used with `.text-md`

Tags: sass, tailwind-css

I'm extracting a helper component by using tailwind utilities and tailwind directives, but when I tried to @apply text-md to a component I get this error:

> `@apply` cannot be used with `.text-md` because `.text-md` either cannot be found, or its actual definition includes a pseudo-selector like :hover, :active, etc
>   .

#### image of code on error situation

[image: image of code on error situation]

#### result without .text-md utilityimage of code on error situation

[image: result without .text-md utilityimage of code on error situation]

Now, What should I do to solve it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That is because by default there is no class `.text-md`.

Comment: Expecting a solution!